# Downloading URL in Python without urllib

Tags: python, html

I have a problem in downloadig URL.

I need to download webpage with the table. When I get `.html` file with the help of  `urllib` or `urllib2`, it has some problems connected with javascript (or same languages). There's only source code such as id_name e.t.c, but it don't have any table information (columns and rows).

Nevertheless, when I save `.html` in Google Chrome, it actually has information in table (not source code, but columns and rows). So what should I do to make it in Python?

Comment: it probably gets populated by javascript

Comment: As @DreadfulWeather said, page can use asynchronous queries to populate a content, so you can use browser's debugger to inspect network queries. Once you find the query with the content, you can use the URL of that query to download with urllib

Answer (score 2):

You can use [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) to simulate browser. It will execute `javascript` then you can get the information you want